# Compiling a cpp file on linux with Windows libraries

Tags: compilation, g++

I would like to solve this issue once for all, what is the best best to compile a .cpp file that uses windows libraries (to create a **exe** file).

For instance I have this cpp starting with:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
```

And I get

```
stdafx.h: No such file or directory
Windows.h: No such file or directory
```

I know for instance that stdafx require Visual C++ on Windows, but I want to compile it on Linux, how would you do ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is you cannot build a Windows executable on Linux. But you can download the free Visual Studio Community Edition to build it on Windows.

`stdafx.h` is a header file in your project. It is used by Visual Studio's pre-compiled headers feature. If you use a predefined project template, Visual Studio will auto-generate `stdafx.h` and mark it for pre-compilation. You then include the common C++ headers, e.g. STL, in `stdafx.h` and include `stdafx.h` in each of your source code files.

When you are not using Visual Studio `stdafx.h` is a convenient place to pull in the standard headers for runtime libraries but serves no other purpose.

`windows.h` is the header file for Windows runtime APIs. The Windows APIs and hence the headers are not available on Linux. If you want to build an executable on Linux to run on Linux then you must replace Windows APIs with the Linux equivalents.